# How to implement the Notification so that deleted row/item does not reappear after swipe to delete?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, notifications, swipe

I would like to ask you how to avoid deleted row/item to reappear in table and collection. Even though after swipe to delete the row is deleted from table, it stays in collection. Also when user comes back to table view, the row that had been deleted is back there.

I was advised to implement Notifications - so can send a message to the collection/table view controller asking them to reload data. Also was told that the bug happens because when the user opens the collection view after deleting a row from the table view the array of memes gets reset.

I did try to write below code to post notification that tableView shall be reloaded after the row is deleted:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        memes.remove(at: indexPath.row) 
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("reloadAfterRowDeleted"), object: nil)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

After I did add observer to implement function didDeleteRow and reload also data in collection view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 118, height: 118)
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didDeleteRow), name: Notification.Name("reloadAfterRowDeleted"), object: nil) 
}

@objc func didDeleteRow() { 
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Still the deleted item reappears in table & collection. Can you please advice how to implement the Notification so that deleted row/item does not reappear after swipe to delete?

Please here is the link for code: https://github.com/Mairoslav/8.2.MeMe.2.0

Comment: It's not enough to simply call `reloadData`; you need to update the array that your collection view uses for its data. The two view controllers each have their own array. Removing the object from the tableview controllers array doesn't change the collection view controller array. You should have a model object that is shared between the two view controllers

Comment: hi @Paulw11 I solve it by applying "appDelegate.memes.remove(at: indexPath.row)" within tableView(_ commit: forRowAt:). Still was trying to apply the concept as per your hint, however cannot figure it out. Now it would be useful since after applying sort button, have two new questions. 1. after reordering the table cells how can I reflect the reordered array also in collection view? 2. how can I keep the reordered array/table cells also after adding a new item/table cell in the array? https://github.com/Mairoslav/8.2.MeMe.2.0